# Can I use html button like asp.net button?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Can I use html button like asp.net button?

And how?
I did not find the solution.

When I want to click html button, I want to trigger something from asp.net ...

Answer (score 2):

Use onclick event:

```
<input type=button onclick="__doPostback('MyButton')" .. />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are HyperLink Buttons as on asp.net as well which would give you the desired result

Answer (score 1):

You can use Submit Button with Form's which does a [POST](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspFormsPost.php) or [GET](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspFormsGet.php) into a form like

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can I assign a css class to input button?

Comment: You can assign css class within every Elemt of HTML ,so yeas of course .

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use a HTML Button instead?

An ASP.NET Button renders as a HTML Button, so anything you wish to apply to an HTML Button, you can do to an ASP.NET Button.

For example the following CSS would work:

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" cssclass="aspbutton" />

input[type="button"].aspbutton { color:red; }
```

If you wish to use javascript `onclick` on an ASP.NET Button, then using `OnClick` will result in a post back and attempt to trigger a Method with that name.

However, you can use `OnClientClick` instead. The following render the same (apart from IDs and Names):

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert('test');" />
<input onclick="alert('test');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but because ASP.NET runs in a server architecture, the input button should have an attribute 'runat' with a value of 'server' e.g. runat="server" to make contact with the ASP.NET web server as ASP scripts runs on the server.

It will then look something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" runat="server" />
```